# What is the Path and Name of a runtime executable?

Tags: python, pi-store

I am trying to upload an [old encryption tool](http://pastebin.com/WkpLQXTY) that I created a while ago to the Pi store. I am almost done, but have reached an issue at the Runtime Settings part of the upload. I need to know, *what is a Runtime Executable path?* Does it have anything to do with my code (the link links to that) or is it used for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime executable path is the full path name of an executable.  In the case of a python script beginning with `#!/usr/bin/python`, it's just the path to the script, eg. `/usr/local/bin/myprogram.py`.

Comment: So... it is basically where my program will be stored on the downloader's computer?

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with the pi store so the context is not clear to me -- whether you are being asked by the pi store installer where you want the installer to put it, vs. being asked where your installer is going to put it -- but either way it does refer to where the executable ends up on the user's system.  So, eg, you may have an app with a directory somewhere to store config files and other things, but the *runtime executable* is probably not in that directory, it is somewhere in the normal $PATH, and the executable then accesses config files etc somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the file you'd like to be run when a user launches your application from inside the Pi Store, *relative to the root of the .zip file you've uploaded*.

So if you wanted to launch 'mygame.py', which is in a 'game' directory at the root of your .zip file, the contents of the field should be `game/mygame.py`.

Auto-completion possibilities should be presented to you in a dropdown as you type in the field. If it's not showing up in the dropdown, it's worth double-checking that you've got the path right.

You can make sure that you've done it correctly by selecting '*Download Current Build*' from the '*Installers/Platforms*' submenu of the project management area. This will let you download and test your app through the Pi Store before it's publicly available.

There's a guide to the meanings of terms used during the upload process [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=26297).